# Wait for a function to finish before proceeding to the next function

Tags: php, function, asynchronous, web-scraping, async-await

I am a novice web developer, and am currently working on a web scraper project.

This is my code so far:

```php
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$URLarray = array(); //empty array that stores list of all Video Page URLs

function getLinks()
{ // this function goes to every VidBlock on the page and add the URL to the array
    $html = file_get_html('https://www.myyouporn.com/');

    $outerBlocksArray = $html->find('h2[class="entry-title"]');

    foreach ($outerBlocksArray as $outerBlock) {

        $URLarray[] = $outerBlock->find('a', 0)->href;
    }
}

getLinks();  // WHAT I NEED IS --> THIS FUNCTION TO COMPLETE BEFORE MOVING AHEAD

print_r($URLarray);

?>
```

I'm using the `simple-html-dom-parser` library.

How do I make my PHP code to wait for the async function to complete, before moving further with the code.

Comment: how this is related  to mysql??

Comment: there is no async function in php

Comment: You need to learn something about scopes to understand what your problem is because: `$URLarray = array();` (global scope) does not reference the same variable as used in `$URLarray[] = $outerBlock->find('a', 0)->href;` (function scope). [Variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)